# Change install directory for Apache Ambari nodes/hosts

Tags: ambari

I have 3 virtual machines that I want to add to an Ambari cluster.

I'm going through the setup wizard to do this.

My VMs have less than 2GB of space in the drive mounted on **/**

Ambari complains about this.

**Is there any way to tell Ambari that I want it to use a different location?**

I would like to tell Ambari to use the **/data** location for each host.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to install an HDP stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're attempting to install an HDP stack. No. You will need more space on the root partition. All of the services (Spark, HBase, HDFS, Yarn, Oozie, etc.) are installed into `/usr/hdp/<version>`. This is not overridable since each of these services is installed using an rpm and the default location in which those rpms install into is hard coded throughout several of the service descriptors that help provision the cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Makes sense.